# the file from torrent stop receiving pieces after a 30%

Tags: bittorrent, libtorrent

I am usin jbittorrent api
 When i download content of torrent from my torrent client it works fine for a certain time and after 2-3 pieces it stop receiving pieces.

Comment: With EVERY file?  Have you tried ones with a high seeder ratio?

Comment: yes, i have tried with high seeder ratio. 
I m making torrent client for android. 
in logcat it is saying that Tracker URL is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some concepts introduced. one of it called choking (Describes a peer to which the client refuses to send file pieces. A client chokes another client in several situations:
The second client is a seed, in which case it does not want any pieces (i.e., it is completely uninterested)
The client is already uploading at its full capacity (it has reached the value of max_uploads)
The second client has been blacklisted for being abusive or is using a blacklisted BitTorrent client.)